# How do I run a node.js app that I installed with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

So I installed Node.js on my Windows machine, opened up command prompt and typed

```
npm ethercalc
```

Lots of lines flew by and it seems ethercalc and its dependencies have been downloaded and installed. Now, how do I run ethercalc?

```
node ethercalc
```

returns a message saying it can't find file "ethercalc" in the *current* directory.

Note: I'm completely new to node.js. I was very surprised that the official website does not contain basic "Getting Started" info.

Comment: As far as "getting started" info, take a quick look at the [`npm install` docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) and there's [plenty of reading about node in general here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Resources).

Answer (score 3):

Since `ethercalc` is an executable, you should install it globally using :

`npm install -g ethercalc`

and then you can run it using:

`ethercalc`

Note, you will probably need to use `sudo` for the install if you are on `linux`.

Alternatively, their [website](http://ethercalc.net/) also mentions installing locally and running the executable from the `node_modules` folder:

```
npm install ethercalc
./node_modules/ethercalc/bin/ethercalc
```

Comment: `install -g` is the way to go, but `sudo` is obviously not applicable on Windows.  (Windows npm installs 'globally' into the user profile folder, so no elevated permissions are necessary.)

Comment: @josh3736 Thanks for the tip. Updated.